# SQL function to grab 1 static and 5 random records from the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know how to select entries from SQL table where first record from column A equals X and select other 5 random (1-10) records from the same column.

I need to retrieve in total 6 entries by one SQL query, where first entry is always static and other five random.

tbl cars

```
ID      COLOUR      CAR

1        green      carX

2        blue       carX

3        green      carY

4        red        carZ

5        black      carA

6        yellow     carB

7        black      carB
```

Required result:

first record of carX, blue(static)

and 5 random

all records should be different from each other - unique

Comment: btw, your required result doesn't match what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to `SELECT` the static row and combine it with a `SELECT` of the random rows provided you have a specific condition.

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE column = 'static condition'
UNION
(SELECT * FROM cars WHERE column != 'static condition' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5)
```

**Note:** If you don't have trouble with the *static condition*, comment back with more detail about your the *static* record.

Comment: it's awesome! thanks a lot for your help, I was actually looking for something simple like that. Good day to you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, that doesn't require 2 selects and a union, is [ORDER BY FIELD](http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Handy_MySQL_-_ORDER_BY_FIELD.cfm);

in my query, I've used the `id` field, to force a specific article to the top.

```
08:34:47 (7) > select id, title FROM articles ORDER BY FIELD(id, 181634, id), RAND() LIMIT 6;
+--------+-----------------+
| id     | title           |
+--------+-----------------+
| 181634 | This is a title | 
| 166289 | This is a title | 
| 152080 | This is a title | 
| 170037 | This is a title | 
| 135411 | This is a title | 
| 171414 | This is a title | 
+--------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.06 sec)

08:35:09 (8) > select id, title FROM articles ORDER BY FIELD(id, 181634, id), RAND() LIMIT 6;
+--------+-----------------+
| id     | title           |
+--------+-----------------+
| 181634 | This is a title | 
| 104905 | This is a title | 
| 103044 | This is a title | 
| 129612 | This is a title | 
| 104157 | This is a title | 
| 160612 | This is a title | 
+--------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```